# Variable %d and += operator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a pattern in python. I need to have all the pages of a set of links (called "subjects_links"): ex. I've www.url/animal (with www.url/animal/page/1 ecc.) and www.url/plants (with www.url/plants/page/1 ecc).
I've done this:

```
n = 1
next_page = subjects_links+'page/%d' % n+=1
```

but gives me an "invalid syntax" error. Is it not possible to use %d and += together?

### Edit

I've found a solution using while and parsing with beautifulsoup:

```
while True:
    next_page = soup_cat.find("a", class_="nextpostslink")
    next_page_link = next_page.get('href')
    print(next_page_link)
    cat_list.append(next_page_link)
    soup_cat = bs4(requests.get(next_page_link).text,'lxml')
```

This changes totally the way of doing it, but at least it works.

Comment: `n+=1` is not a value, so you can't use it as a substitution value. You can use `(n+1)`, or you can incremente `n` separately.

Comment: n+=1 is assignment operation, it's not JavaScript, in Python you cannot use assignment as a statement that returns value. Do n+=1 on line before or after your operation.

Comment: Or, if you need to do this a lot, you could roll your own wrapper class providing an `incrementAndGet` method. Also, where does ´n` come from? This seems to be some kind of loop, maybe over some collection of results, so maybe you can just use `enumerate`?

Comment: It would be way easier and readable to write n+=1 and use just n.

Answer (score 2):

Since python 3.8, you'll be able to use the assignment expression. n += 1 is am assignment statement.

```
next_page = subjects_links+'page/%d' % (n := n+1)
```

Comment: So I need to upgrade from 3.7 to 3.8?

Comment: @Lara You don't have to. AFAIK 3.8 is in development. You can use the other solutions, although this one is slightly more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

`n += 1`  is an [augmented-assignment-statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) and you are trying to use it as an [expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html).

The following does work:

```
n = 0

n += 1
print("page/%d" % n)
```

*Note: I've modified the example so it can run on it's own*

Comment: This just prints me the first page, not the others

Comment: Even if I make:`n = 0
n += 1
print('page/%d' % n)` it doesn't takes more pages than one